# Split line into two Strings using BufferedReader Java

Tags: java, bufferedreader

how do i read "`Dr. Dr. John Doe John@Doe.com`"(line_split[0]) into two separate strings(name and email in MailEntry,  . The name has unlimited words.

```
ArrayList<MailEntry> Daten = new ArrayList<MailEntry>();

try {
    File file = new File("MailDaten.txt");
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] line_split = line.split(" ");
        Daten.add(new MailEntry(line_split[0], line_split[5],
                new TimeEntry(line_split[1], line_split[2], line_split[3], line_split[4])));
        stringBuffer.append(line);
        stringBuffer.append("\n");
    }
    fileReader.close();
    System.out.println("Contents of file:");
    System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: If the name can have unlimited words, why are you using hard-coded indexes?

Comment: Have you tried searching in google for regular expression for emailid in a string for java

Comment: Strictly speaking, an email address is allowed to contain spaces, if they are in a quoted string. So splitting by space as the first step is a bad idea. It's really important to realize that an e-mail address can be a lot more than the "normal" a.b.c@example.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a regex to split it. You want to split on only the last space:

```
\\s+(?=[^\\s]*$)

    \\s+    - whitspace for 1 or more characters
    (?=  )  - a group that is not included. will not be used up by the split
    [^\\s]* - not whitespace for any amount of characters
    $       - end of line
```

Example use case:

```
String test = "Dr. Dr. John Doe John@Doe.com";
String regex = "\\s+(?=[^\\s]*$)";
String[] result = test.split(regex);
System.out.println(result[0]);
System.out.println(result[1]);
```

Which prints:

```
Dr. Dr. John Doe
John@Doe.com
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, an email address (the local part) is allowed to contain spaces, if they are in a quoted string.

Comment: @RealSkeptic hmmm, that makes this problem much harder

Answer (score 0):

You can use following approach for your requirement-

1. Split each entry into list of tokens seperated by space.
2. Iterate thesd tokens and check for '@'    in each token. If it exists, copy it as email adress.
3. Else concatinate token seprated by space. This would give you name.

Hope this answers you query! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Just Executed it

```
String test = "Dr. Dr. John Doe John@Doe.com";
        int  s = test.split("@")[0].lastIndexOf(" ");
        String s1 = test.substring(0,s);
        String s2 = test.substring(s+1,test.length());
        System.out.println(s1);
        System.out.println(s2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the email and subtract it from the actual string. You can use the split function or use the indexOf function. Use of the split function is shown above. You can also do the following.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final String nameAndMail = "Dr. Dr. John Doe John@Doe.com";
    String name = "";
    String mail = "";
    final String mailPattern = "\\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}\\b";
    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(mailPattern,
            Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    final Matcher matcher = p.matcher(nameAndMail);
    final Set<String> mailList = new HashSet<String>(); // If you have multiple emails in the string

    while (matcher.find()) {
        mail = matcher.group();
        // mailList.add(mail);
        name = nameAndMail.substring(0, nameAndMail.indexOf(mail));
    }
    System.out.println("Name is::" + name);
    System.out.println("Mail is::" + mail);
}
```

Output of above code is:

```
Name is::Dr. Dr. John Doe     
Mail is::John@Doe.com
```

Comment: you can change the regex part to make it more flexible. If the string contains multiple emails then inside the while loop you can add mail variable to an ArrayList.